# Forget index using it key value in laravel session

Tags: php, laravel, session, eloquent

**Result of $ compare:-**

[image]

**code:-**

```
public function remove(Request $request)
{
    $compare = $request->session()->get('compare', collect([]));
    $compare->forget($request->id);
    
    
    
    return back();
    
}
```

**I want to delete data inside array $compare that i am retrieving data from session but delete relevant index including its value, using the key value.**

```
array:3 [
     0 => "4"
     1 => "2"
     2 => "1"   ]
```

`forget()` or `pull()`
`0 => "4"`
using it's value `"4"`

Answer (score 0):

You need [`filter`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-filter):

```php
$compare->filter(function ($value, $key) use ($request) {
    // return only the values that don't match the request id
    return $value !== $request->id;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to know its key to use `forget()`.
If you want to remove item by value, you can use either `filter()` or `reject()`

```
$id = $request->id;

$filtered = $compare->filter(function($value) use ($id) {
    return $value !== $id;
});

$filtered = $compare->reject(function($value) use ($id) {
    return $value === $id;
});
```

To store data in the session you can use `session()` helper to set the value by the key so for the `compare` key it would be like this.

```
session('compare', $filtered);
```

Comment: Would you please let me know how i could use this code to delete/forget the session value... $compare->forget($request->id); I have tried this but it is not returning desired key of the value.

Comment: @SaadHamza yes, updated the answer to include setting the session value.